# South African born travelling to SA on NZ passport

Tags: dual-nationality, south-africa, new-zealand, south-african-citizens, new-zealand-citizens

I am travelling to South Africa for the first time since we emigrated to New Zealand in 1999.

My understanding has always been that my SA citizenship was revoked when I became a NZ citizen. A new SA court ruling in 2023 has changed that and all people in this situation have regained their citizenship.

By law, SA requires all citizens to enter the country on a SA passport. I haven't held one for almost 20 years. Will I be able to enter SA on my NZ passport or am I going to have issues with the new law?

Comment: When are you travelling? Isn’t the simplest option to just get an SA passport?

Comment: I am travelling in a couple of weeks, and was only made aware of it yesterday. No way for me to get a passport before then.

Comment: Presumably you didn't just learn you are a citizen again and decide to book flights for the soonest date after that, so you had a reasonable expectation of entering the country without being a citizen anyway. In that case, follow the original plan, and sort out the wrong-entry-documents issue later.